# How to use ifelse using mutate to get a new column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

A  simple sample of my data is shown below

```html
   

 Id   x   y   
 12 Yellow  Yellow    
 13 Yellow  Blue      
 10 Blue    Yellow    
 14 Blue    Blue      
 19 Yellow  Yellow
```

And I want to get this

```html
Id  x   y   z
12  Yellow  Yellow  Y
13  Yellow  Blue    N
10  Blue    Yellow  N
14  Blue    Blue    N
19  Yellow  Yellow  Y
```

When x and y are  only Yellow, I get Y, else N for the z column

I have tried this, but it does not help me.

```html
dat%>% mutate(z=ifelse(x=="Yellow") & (ifelse(y=="yellow")),"Y","N")
```

Comment: You need `ifelse(x %in% c("Yellow", "yellow"), "Y", "N")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
dat %>% mutate(z=ifelse(x=="Yellow" & y == "Yellow", "Y", "N"))
```

Or maybe this:

```
dat %>% mutate(z=ifelse(tolower(x)=="yellow" & tolower(y) == "yellow", "Y", "N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need two `ifelse`.  Also, the `ifelse` for first and second only had the 'test' condition, without the 'yes' or 'no' i.e.  According to `?ifelse`, usage is

> ifelse(test, yes, no)

In the OP's post, the `ifelse` got closed after the `test` condition

```
ifelse(y=="yellow")
         ^test condition
```

---

For multiple elements, instead of `==`, can use `%in%`

```
dat$z <- c("N", "Y")[Reduce(`&`, lapply(dat[-1], `%in%`, c('yellow', 'Yellow'))) + 1]
dat$z
#[1] "Y" "N" "N" "N" "Y"
```

Comment: I do not get a decent result when I use large data.

Comment: @Rose can you please explain a bit more.  I didn't get what you meant by decent

Comment: I get Yellow and Blue or vis versa as "Y" in large data

Comment: @Rose Can you show the `str(dat)`.  Is it a `factor` or `character` column?

Comment: @Rose Maybe there are some leading/lagging spaces.  Can you try the updated `dat %>%
      mutate(z = ifelse(tolower(trimws(x))  == 'yellow', 'Y', 'N'))`

Comment: No sorry, the same result. Both  are characters

Comment: @Rose How about `dat %>% mutate(z = ifelse(grepl("yellow", x, ignore.case = TRUE), "Y", "N"))`

Comment: The same results

Comment: @Rose I am very sorry.  I thought it is the single 'x' column.  instead of 'x' and 'y'

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R option without `ifelse`

```
transform(
  df,
  z = c("N", "Y")[1 + (rowSums(cbind(x, y) == "Yellow") == 2)]
)
```

which gives

```
  Id      x      y z
1 12 Yellow Yellow Y
2 13 Yellow   Blue N
3 10   Blue Yellow N
4 14   Blue   Blue N
5 19 Yellow Yellow Y
```